# QuickBooks Web Connector Error: The element 'QBXML' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

I have a web server connecting to QuickBooks Desktop via the Web Connector.  Most of my transaction types are working, but I have a few which are not.  When I run them through the XML validator, I get this error:

Requested validation for QB Web Connector (qwc), file has processing instruction indicating <?qbxml... obeying processing instruction
Line: 2
LinePos: 8
Src Text: 
Reason: The element 'QBXML' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema.

My QBXML is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?><?qbxml version="13.0"?> 
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError">
    <ReceivePaymentAddRq requestID = "2">
      <ReceivePaymentAdd>
        <CustomerRef>
          <ListID>8000017D-1509724466</ListID>
        </CustomerRef>
        <TxnDate>2016-01-04</TxnDate>                
        <RefNumber>1000</RefNumber>                      
        <TotalAmount>39.99</TotalAmount>     
        <PaymentMethodRef>            
          <FullName>Cash</FullName>   
        </PaymentMethodRef>
        <AppliedToTxnAdd>                        
          <TxnID>81E-1509734863</TxnID>
          <PaymentAmount>39.99</PaymentAmount>  
        </AppliedToTxnAdd>
      </ReceivePaymentAdd>
    </ReceivePaymentAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The XML validator says the QBXML is valid for both the Desktop and On-Line versions, but gives the error when testing for the Web Connector

I'm having this issue with EmployeeAdd, ReceivePaymentAdd and PaymentMethodAdd.  I'm not having it with AccountAdd, ClassAdd, CustomerAdd, ItemServiceAdd or InvoiceAdd.

I've tried changing the Version to everything between 2.0 and 13.0

Has anyone else run across this and found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

> When I run them through the XML validator, I get this error:

You're using the wrong settings in the validator.

- You should NEVER be validating against the `Web Connector` option
  (that is for validating `.qwc` files, vs. actual `qbXML` requests)
- You should NEVER be validating against `Online` (QuickBooks Online no
  longer uses qbXML at all)
- Always validate against the `Desktop` version option

If you're experiencing errors, then you *need to post the actual error you're getting* along with the actual requests that you're sending so that we can help you.

Comment: I'm getting error from web connector so checked logs. Payment record synced successfully (to QBD) but the response from QBD seems broken. I used XML validator for the qbxml response (paymentadd) and it says above issue. what's happening here?

Comment: What's the error? What's broken about it? Did you post your code?

Comment: there was a php error, I used XML validator for the response from QBD. Everything is all right!!